# Intel® Core™2 Duo Desktop Processor vs Intel® Core™ i3 Desktop Processor?

Tags: cpu, memory, intel-core2, intel-core-i3

Intel® Core™2 Duo Desktop Processor vs Intel® Core™ i3 Desktop Processor?

Which CPU is better to buy ?

**Intel® Core™ i3-530 Processor (4M Cache, 2.93 GHz)** (*it supports DDR3 also*)

or

**Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E7500 (3M Cache, 2.93 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB)** (*it supports DDR2 only* )

Although I do not play games on my PC but I need good performance in Adobe Photoshop, Watching Full HD Movies. I need good performance in Multitasking.

Along with any of these CPU I would purchase 2 GB x 2 stick of RAM. and I will use Windows 7. and I will use [Microsoft VPC images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) also with MS Virtual PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i3 processor is better, specs-wise, architecture-wise as well as via benchmarks as [per Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/bench/Product/87?vs=118)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  but for Adobe Photoshop C2D showing better.

Comment: Am I missing something? It says the Core 2 Duo takes 29.2 seconds for a Photoshop retouch and the i3 takes 25 seconds. Lower is better.

Comment: @taspeotis - Oh sorry. It was my misunderstanding.